# updating the position of a JQuery UI draggable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, iscroll4, jquery-ui-touch-punch

If I scroll a page the currently dragged draggable stays in the same position. This leads to the finger not being above the draggable anymore. Is there any way in which I could update the position of a draggable to the current touch location without removing the draggable functionality?

My setup is rather complicated using iScrolls scrollTo method for Scrolling and jQuery-Ui-Touch Punch for touch support, but this should apply to other cases of draggable and touch/click position-mismatch as well.

Comment: Solved it by appending the draggable to a position:absolute element outside of the iScroll wrapper. In this way it doesn't scroll. I won't mark it as solved because it's not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

update: function (event, ui) {

```
    var data = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();

   //use ajax to update the position
```

}